# Why are lw and sw byte addressable but jump and beq word addressable?

Tags: mips, assembly

I am refering to MIPS (32 bits).

Is there any particular reason that when loading or storing a word, we address memory in bytes, but when we jump or branch using beq we address memory in words?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On MIPS, each instruction is exactly one word long, and is byte-aligned to words. Hence it makes no sense to jump to a byte address in the middle of a word, because that can't be the legal start of an instruction. Because the lower two bits of a jump address must be zero, you can describe more higher-order bits in the instruction encoding.